# My Jquery doesn't seem to find panelid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i followed this video to write smarter but my code isn't working like his. So my conclusion is that my jquery doesnt seem to find panelid, I can alert the panelids and that works. My function is to click on "läs mer" and a text should pop out, and läs mer changes to mindre- .Where do i go from here?! Im going insane soon.

The YT video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cc3K2jDdKTo

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li> <a data-panelid="panel1" class="showhide" href="#">Läs mer +</a> </li>
    <li> <a data-panelid="panel2" class="showhide" href="#">Läs mer +</a> </li>
    <li> <a data-panelid="panel3" class="showhide" href="#">Läs mer +</a> </li>
</ul>
<div id="panel1" class="textstyle">Ett enda bett från inlandstaipanen innehåller tillräckligt mycket gift för att döda upp till 100 vuxna människor eller 250 000 möss.</div>
<div id="panel2" class="textstyle">ouahsfouashfoas aushfaslal.</div>
<div id="panel3" class="textstyle">ioajsfoiasjgoiashfoas oahsgkmaspof.</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".showhide").click(function() {
        var panelId = $(this).attr('data-panelid')
        alert(panelId);
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(panelId).toggle();
        if (txt == "Läs mer +") {
            $(this).text('Mindre -');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Läs mer +');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks you for everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `#`

```
$('#'+panelId)
```

and
use [`.data() method`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
  var panelId =  $(this).data('panelid');
```

[**Corrected Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/haby6d6r/)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), so add `#` with `panelId`

```
$('#' + panelId)
```

If your variable value is `panel1` then `$(panelId)` will look for element `panel1` which doesn't exists, thus its not working

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much for the help! But it's still not working, I think the problem is that the paneled can't find the div id sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @CodingNoob: this should work if you have correct panelid. try getting the panel id using data method `var panelId = $(this).data('panelid')`

Comment: @CodingNoob : I have added a demo in my answer..it works well

Comment: DAAAAMN ITS WOOOORKIING WOOOHOOO. I CANT THANK YOU ENAUGH GUYS. Was stuck with this 3h yesterday and I'm so lucky to find such website to help. I definitely will use this in future when I'm stuck. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jsfiddle link where you can see it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4xd3u05/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".showhide").click(function() {
        var panelId = $(this).attr('data-panelid')
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $('#' + panelId).toggle(); //changed it here from just panelId
        if (txt == "Läs mer +") {
            $(this).text('Mindre -');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Läs mer +');
        }
    });
});
```